# proguard IllegalArgumentException

Tags: proguard, minify, shrink

Trying to build release version of my application. It comes up with an error saying that

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue]
```

I saw a similar case here: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/573/

I have already added `-optimizations !class/unbosing/enum`
but the error still shows 
there is no change. Maybe I am missing something else from the proguard-rules?

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontobfuscate
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Keep all things of data model classes
-keep public class com.hotmob.sdk.model.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class MyClass;

-Adagger.android.experimentalUseStringKeys

# gson
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# android-saripaar
-keep class com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.** { *; }
-keep @com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.ValidateUsing class * { *; }

# loading icon
-keep class com.wang.avi.** { *; }
-keep class com.wang.avi.indicators.** { *; }
```

This is the error that shows

```
Optimizing (pass 1/5)...
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$classes$1]
  Method      = [invoke(Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$FindClassRequest;)Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/descriptors/ClassDescriptor;]
  Instruction = [311] ificmpne +113 (target=424)
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue])
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$classes$1]
  Method      = [invoke(Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$FindClassRequest;)Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/descriptors/ClassDescriptor;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue])
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue]
Thread(Tasks limiter_2): destruction

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

The stacktrack debug shows pretty much the same

```
19:04:39.831 [ERROR] [system.err] Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
19:04:39.831 [ERROR] [system.err]   Class       = [kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$classes$1]
19:04:39.832 [ERROR] [system.err]   Method      = [invoke(Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$FindClassRequest;)Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/descriptors/ClassDescriptor;]
19:04:39.833 [ERROR] [system.err]   Instruction = [311] ificmpne +113 (target=424)
19:04:39.833 [ERROR] [system.err]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue])
19:04:39.834 [ERROR] [system.err] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
19:04:39.834 [ERROR] [system.err]   Class       = [kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$classes$1]
19:04:39.834 [ERROR] [system.err]   Method      = [invoke(Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/descriptors/LazyJavaPackageScope$FindClassRequest;)Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/descriptors/ClassDescriptor;]
19:04:39.834 [ERROR] [system.err]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue])
19:04:40.541 [QUIET] [system.out] Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value "a" is not an integer value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownReferenceValue]
19:04:40.550 [QUIET] [system.out] Thread(Tasks limiter_1): destruction
19:03:00.186 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
19:03:00.186 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
19:04:40.550 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute transform for :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute transform for :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' completed
19:04:40.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter] Fingerprinting property otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput1 (Output) for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter] Fingerprinting property otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput2 (Output) for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.570 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter] Fingerprinting property otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput3 (Output) for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.579 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter] Fingerprinting property streamOutputFolder (Output) for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.579 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep] Not storing result of task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' in cache because the execution failed
19:04:40.580 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
19:04:40.581 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
19:04:40.583 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
19:04:40.583 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
```

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?